# .val() select text instead the value string when the webpage dinamically edits the source html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html on a web page:

```
<select name="chapter_select" class="chapter_select">
<option value="http://www.example.com/chapter/1">Chapter 1</option>
<option value="http://www.example.com/chapter/2">Chapter 2</option>
<option value="http://www.example.com/chapter/3">Chapter 3</option>
<option value="http://www.example.com/chapter/4">Chapter 4</option>
<option value="http://www.example.com/chapter/5">Chapter 5</option>
<option value="http://www.example.com/chapter/6" selected="selected">Chapter 6</option>
</select>
```

And this variables:

```
getInformationsFromCurrentPage : function(doc, curUrl, callback) {
//This function runs in the DOM of the current consulted page
var curChapName = $("select.chapter_select:first option:selected", doc).text();
var chapurl = $("select.chapter_select:first option:selected", doc).val();
callback({"name": name, 
        "currentChapter": curChapName, 
        "currentMangaURL": nameurl, 
        "currentChapterURL": chapurl});
},
}
```

The problem is that both return the same text value. chapurl should return the url, not the text value. This was working until the website modified their site.

I know that I'm going to be pretty picky but this is the manual for the development of the extension and the doc variable is a must http://www.allmangasreader.com/dev.php just look out for the getInformationsFromCurrentPage function. It's using the jQuery 1.4.2 so maybe its that, the weird thing is that other sites just work as it.

UPDATE: The server was using a script (rewriting the html) making me think that the dropdown list was on the top. I used some selectors to get the correct one following the source.

Comment: I get the URL if I remove the doc object:  http://jsfiddle.net/fs49g/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could always use a fallback and use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). This way you can always gaurantee that you'll be getting the value.

```
var chapval = $("select.chapter_select:first option:selected").attr('value');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dt5PV/

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately don't work, return the chapter name, like .val()

Comment: @braiam If that doesn't work I *guarantee* you that you are either targeting the wrong drop-down list (another one occurs before the one you are targeting, so it's `:first`), or the server is rewriting your markup before it passes the html to the browser. Use a tool like firebug to inspect the `<select>` element and check the markup and/or post a jsfiddle with your full (relevant) html that reproduces the problem

Comment: @nbrooks The site rewrite the first select using a script and take the values from #page #content #assets #asset_1 and I was using #content #manga_nav_top, now its working. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

```
var curChapName = $("select.chapter_select:first option:selected", doc).text();
var chapurl = $("select.chapter_select:first option:selected", doc).val();
```

this work http://jsfiddle.net/ so there must be something wrong with your doc variable, please inspect it

Comment: that's is part of the function of the extension, if I delete it would return nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
var curChapName = $("select.chapter_select:first :selected").text()
var chapurl = $("select.chapter_select:first").val()
```